# Intel TBB for OpenCV pow and sqrt

Tags: c++, opencv, parallel-processing, tbb

In my c++ image processing algorithm, Mat.mul(), cv::pow and cv::sqrt are the most time consuming operations. Is it possible to speed up these operations using Intel TBB?
Do I need to write my own matrix mul,pow and sqrt functions to enable TBB support (e.g. using parallel_for for iterating over mat) or is TBB support included for these functions in OpenCV?
Are there any diffrent approaches for paralization of these functions?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the question '[OpenCV TBB IPP OpenMP functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716639/opencv-tbb-ipp-openmp-functions)' regarding what OpenCV parallels. It doesn't seem these functions are parallel (though they are optimized using IPP). And the reason I guess is because there is no much work per one call to these functions to justify a fork of a parallel work. At this bottom-level of the program, vectorization (SIMD, data-parallelism) is more appropriate. TBB should rather be applied from the top-level of the application first, leveraging functional or (outermost) loop parallelism (pipeline, graph, parallel_for).